# Buffer not displaying and reference points disappearing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have created 'reference points' on QGIS 3.6.3 and ensured I am using a metric coordinate system. The reference points and all data display correctly but when I attempt to add a 150m buffer around these 'reference points' (using either processing toolbox -> vector geometry -> buffer OR processing toolbox -> GDAL->vector geoprocessing -> buffer vectors) the reference points disappear and the buffer does not appear on the map, despite being created as a layer.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: SOLVED - But don't know how to delete question

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question detailing the solution, which might help someone with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/